# python numpy filter ndarray based on an element value

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy ndarray as below. I want to filter rows, cols where the fourth coordinate is not 1.
i.e, where ndarary[0][0][-1] != 1

```
>>> print(ndarray)
array([[[0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1]],

       ...,

       [[0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1]]], dtype=uint8)
```

Code I tried and which worked:

```
row_cols = []

for ir, row in enumerate(ndarray):
  for ic, col in enumerate(row):
    if col[-1] != 1:
      row_cols.append((ir,ic))
```

But this is O(N^2) solution and highly time consuming, since the ndarray is of shape (800,1280*4) and I have to perform this on several thousands of arrays.

Is there a better way to filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numpy slicing op an `np.where` function will help you:

```
np.random.seed(2020)
array = np.random.randint(0, 3, 36).reshape([4, 3, 3])
```

where `array` is:

```
array([[[0, 0, 2],
    [1, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0]],
   [[2, 1, 2],
    [2, 2, 1],
    [0, 0, 0]],
   [[0, 2, 0],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [2, 1, 2]],
   [[1, 1, 2],
    [2, 2, 2],
    [1, 0, 2]]])
```

Results of your code:

```
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2)]
```

Using slicing and `np.where`:

```
simple_array = array[..., -1]
ir, ic = np.where(simple_array != 1)
```

The `ir` is:

```
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], dtype=int64)
```

The `ic` is:

```
array([0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2], dtype=int64)
```

Performance:

```
import numpy as np
from time import time

array = np.random.randint(0, 4, 800 * 1280 * 4).reshape([800, 1280, 4])
start = time()
row_cols = []

for ir, row in enumerate(array):
    for ic, col in enumerate(row):
        if col[-1] != 1:
            row_cols.append((ir, ic))
print(time() - start)  # 0.6560261249542236
start = time()
simple_array = array[..., -1]
ir, ic = np.where(simple_array != 1)
print(time() - start)  # 0.02800583839416504
```